# Directional derivatives in differential geometry

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, differential-geometry

The directional derivative of a differentiable vector field $Y$ at a point $p$ along a fixed directional vector $X$ is defined as $D_XY|_p:=DY|_p(X)$, where $DY$ denotes the jacobian matrix. However, I'm a little confused as in, what 'jacobian' are we talking about here? Take for example a 3-dimensional curve $c(t)$ parametrized by $(t,t,t^2)$, by my book $D_{c'}c'=c''$. We check that $c''=(0,0,2)$, whereas the jacobian of $c'$ is just $(0,0,2)^T$. Now if we do $DY|_p(X)$ we get $(0,0,2)^T(1,1,2t)^T$ which doesn't really work out, since we're now trying to multiply matrices that aren't suppose to be multipled. What has gone wrong in the above steps?

Comment: I would be really grateful if someone can show how it should be done, and how the directional derivative turns out to be c'', after the calculation of some jacobian. Thanks.

Comment: Are you only interested in Euclidean space (as ambient space)?